# differences between linux and windows makefile?

Tags: c, linux, windows, makefile

Already build a C program in Windows environment and make this makefile

```
# project name (generate executable with this name)
TARGET   = Orga_L1_MATURANA

CC       = gcc
# compiling flags here
CFLAGS   = -Wall -I.

LINKER   = gcc
# linking flags here
LFLAGS   = -Wall -I. -lm

# change these to proper directories where each file should be
SRCDIR   = src
OBJDIR   = obj
BINDIR   = bin

SOURCES  := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/main.c)
OBJECTS  := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
rm       = rm -f


$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @$(LINKER) $(OBJECTS) $(LFLAGS) -o $@
    @echo "Linking complete!"

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    @echo "Compiled "$<" successfully!"
```

and this tree's see of the code

```
.
├── bin
│   ├── lineasControl2.txt
│   ├── mipsEjemplo2.asm
│   └── Orga_L1_MATURANA
├── makefile
├── obj
│   └── main.o
├── README.md
└── src
    ├── 2EnlazadasCursor.c
    ├── cons.c
    ├── cons.h
    ├── funciones.c
    ├── funciones.h
    ├── main.c
    ├── operaciones.c
    └── structs.h
```

its fine the way that im doing the makefile for both OS? Besides, i hear that ubuntu doesnt needs a makefile, is that right? I dont think so.

Comment: I recommend installing and using Linux on your own laptop. It is very developer and student friendly.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks to you! I already do, but this was a homework and the enviroment was a non-functional requirement, so, im trying to build it in ubuntu, trying to do it multriplataform. thx for the advice.

Comment: Then you can test `make` on both systems; BTW read more [about `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) and run perhaps `make --trace` and `make -p`

Comment: You may consider `make` and its *Makefile* sources as functional programming language (which is actually is, but for certain niche). Thus, depending on engine you need to use different slang of *Nakefile* or exact engine on different OSes.

Comment: As long as all you do is using native GNU make features there's no problem with any OS. The problem comes when you use external program, by example to move files.

Comment: "rm -f" doesn't look like a command that Windows cmd.exe would understand natively, so perhaps there is something else in play here besides make and gcc? Is this MingGW perhaps? Or Cygwin? I've found that with MinGW, and a bit of care, I can use the same Makefile for Windows and Linux, even for some quite complex, graphical applications.

Comment: When defining macros, the use of `=` generates a macro that will be re-evaluated each time that it is referenced.  Almost always better to us `:=` so the macro is only evaluated once.

Comment: normally, when performing the compile rule, want to list all the included header files as dependencies, so if a header file is changed, the *.c file is recompiled.  There are ways to have `make` generate files that contain the dependencies then have `make` include that file that contains the dependencies when performing the compile step.  Such modification(s) to the `makefile` assures that no header file change is ever overlooked.

Comment: this line: `SOURCES  := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/main.c)` will ONLY find the `main.c` file.  What about all the other *.c files?  Suggest something like: `SOURCES  := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)`

Comment: I would expect the `obj` sub directory should (after running `make` to contain either nothing or `2EnlazadasCursor.o  cons.o funciones.o main.o operaciones.o`  Note: the files ending with `.o` will be eliminated by `make` unless the `makefile` script defines them as `.precious`

Comment: this line: `$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c` looks unlikely to work as expected.  Suggest: `$(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c`

Comment: this file: `operaciones.c` probably contains one or more functions.  So it should have a header file that properly prototypes those functions.

Comment: The makefile should be checking if certain environment names are available, so it can things like `#ifdef WINDOWS ... #else ... #endif so as to work with the proper utilities, depending on which OS is being used.

Comment: If everything is using `gcc` for compiling, linking (then 'windows' is never being used)   Suggest reading the manual for `gnu make`  as there are lots of 'short cut' operators (like $@ $^ $< $> and many more that will greatly reduce the amount of typing needed and make the `makefile` scrip much more flexible.